# How to return raw HTML (using Flask)

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, mailchimp

How can I make a Flask view publish just the raw HTML (unrendered) that was generated by app?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question; but it seems like mailchimp's transactional email product [mandrill](http://mandrill.com) would be better suited for you. It has an [API for templates](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/templates.html) that would simplify your project a lot.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid I'll be sure to investigate. Second week on the job, so just knocking out some smaller projects for the moment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the mime type of the response to `text/plain` using [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.make_response):

```
from flask import app, make_response, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    resp = make_response(render_template('template.html'))
    resp.mimetype = 'text/plain'
    return resp
```

Comment: +1 for adding the link (I edited your post to add some context for the link).